# WPF - Filling a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, addition

I have a 2 column ListView and I'm trying to fill it using and IDictionary with the following code.

```
System.Collections.IDictionary entryList = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry de in entryList)
{
    Row row = new Row();
    row.Name1 = (string)de.Key;
    row.Name2 = (string)de.Value;
    this.list1.Items.Add(row);
}

public class Row
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="varList"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Height="400"
    Width="500"
    Margin="0, 30, 0, 0">

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Name" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="350" Header="Path" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But every row and column gets filled with "Project.Views.Row".
Anyone got any idea on how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: What type are you storing in the dictionary?

Comment: I'm storing an IDictionary... I'm actually using the return of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)

Comment: XAML added... I joined the dev team recently and they weren't using any datasource at all on any list/grid... I just kept it this way because they were doing things this way. :(

Comment: @LucasBertone They were doing it wrong. Be the force of change for good on your team! :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET working on that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ListView` (and every other control for that matter) will display the results of calling `ToString` when given an object to display.

For a standard class, thats its qualified name; Project.Views.Row in your example.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Don't add an object. Instead, format the string as you want it ie:

   ```
   list1.Items.Add(String.Format({0}:{1}, row.Name1, row.Name2));
   ```
2. Do this the *right* way and use MVVM. In this case your XAML needs a data template:

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name1}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name2}"/>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
   ```

   For a grid view:

   ```
    <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name1}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name2}"/>
       </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
   ```

Binding the `ItemsSource` is not *actually* necessary, but since we are doing everything the right way, you should do it so you are not directly manipulating the UI from code.

Comment: @LucasBertone No problem. I didn't give a very thorough explanation of the binding system, so make sure to read up on MVVM with WPF; you'll get a much better understanding of how to generate this.

Comment: Yeah... I'll take a proper look into it and do everything right the next time :D